# How to make a history for a web browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm making my own web browser for the iPad, and I have a problem while I'm trying to make the history. Here's the code:

```
.m
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self historyMethod];
//more settings...
}

-(void)historyMethod{
NSString *googleString= @"http://www.google.es";
    NSString *currentURLString=TextField.text;
    [historyArray addObject:googleString];
    if ([googleString isEqual: currentURLString]) {
        googleString = nil;
        [TableView reloadData];
    }


    [historyArray addObject: currentURLString ];
    [TableView reloadData];

}
```

The problem that I have is that the `historyMethod` is executed just one time, and I need it working all the time! Since I'm a newbie, I don't know too much about methods, and how I can make it work well. I tried it with a `while loop` but it didn't work. Please help me people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want the method to be called repeatedly?
you can use something like `NSTimer` to repeat a method call;

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(historyMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This will call your method every 1 seconds, place this in your `viewDidLoad` method, instead of calling your `historyMethod`.

However, if you don't understand methods, I'd recommend some looking for some Objective-C tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `UIWebView` then you might wanna make your controller a `UIWebViewDelegate`.

By implementing `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` you could keep track
of pages being loaded. Inside this delegate method you can get URL by `webview.request.URL`

Take a look at:

[UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIWebViewDelegateProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)